# How do I make the boost/asio library repeat a timer?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, boost-thread

Here is the Code given on the Boost library documentation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

void print(const boost::system::error_code& /*e*/)
{
  std::cout << "Hello, world!\n";
}

int main()
{
  boost::asio::io_service io;

  boost::asio::deadline_timer t(io, boost::posix_time::seconds(5));
  t.async_wait(print);

  io.run();

  return 0;
}
```

Now when I run the above program it just waits for 5 seconds and then prints Hello World and stop. 
I want this program to keep printing Hello World every 5 seconds.
Is it possible ?

Answer (score 10):

You can do this by calling `deadline_timer::expires_from_now` and `deadline_timer::async_wait` in your timer handler, this will add a timer once last one expires. for example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

void print(const boost::system::error_code& /*e*/,
    boost::asio::deadline_timer* t, int* count)
{
  if (*count < 5)
  {
    std::cout << *count << std::endl;
    ++(*count);

    t->expires_at(t->expires_at() + boost::posix_time::seconds(5));
    t->async_wait(boost::bind(print,
          boost::asio::placeholders::error, t, count));
  }
}

int main()
{
  boost::asio::io_service io;

  int count = 0;
  boost::asio::deadline_timer t(io, boost::posix_time::seconds(5));
  t.async_wait(boost::bind(print,
        boost::asio::placeholders::error, &t, &count));

  io.run();

  std::cout << "Final count is " << count << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

code is from the [Boosts Asio tutorials](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer3.html).

Comment: Note that this does not handle the case when someone wants to cancel your timer. If you aren't careful, and are using multiple threads you can end up with a race condition between cancelling the timer and the timer handler scheduling a new timer wait.

Also, you likely want to handler the timer error codes.