# Boost ASIO server - detecting idle connection

Tags: c++, boost, tcp, boost-asio

The intention of this post is to figure out how to implement a Keep-Alive timeout on a Boost ASIO based HTTP server.

There are 2 parts to this -

1. When the client has closed the connection
2. When the client connection is inactive

I believe, 1) above can be detected by setting the TCP_KEEPIDLE, TCP_KEEPCNT and TCP_KEEPINTVL options on the native socket handle.

What is the best way to detect 2) above?

I have tried setting the SO_RCVTIMEO and SO_SNDTIMEO on the native socket, but the server doesn't seem to close the connection at the end of the configured timeout interval.

Any pointers are much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: If the client closes its connection nicely, then your end of the connection will be marked as readable (if you use polling) and then `read` or `recv` will return `0`.

Answer (score 3):

You want to detect the case when the client has not sent you anything for X amount of time.  You can do this using a timer in Asio: [How do I make the boost/asio library repeat a timer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30389323/how-do-i-make-the-boost-asio-library-repeat-a-timer)

Either construct one timer object per client, or construct one global timer and check the last message received time for all clients every time the timer fires.

`SO_RCVTIMEO` won't help you, because when it expires the receive call returns `EAGAIN` or similar, and Asio will probably not do anything with this.  Read about that here: [SO_RCVTIME and SO_RCVTIMEO not affecting Boost.Asio operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30410265/so-rcvtime-and-so-rcvtimeo-not-affecting-boost-asio-operations)