# Make a Timer with boost::asio::deadline_timer

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I want to make a Timer class with boost::asio::deadline_timer. I looked into this:
[How do I make the boost/asio library repeat a timer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30389323/how-do-i-make-the-boost-asio-library-repeat-a-timer)

```
    class DeadlineTimer
    {
        boost::asio::io_service io;
        std::function<void()> fun;
        boost::asio::deadline_timer t;
        void runTimer()
        {
            fun();
            t.expires_at(t.expires_at() + boost::posix_time::seconds(2));
            t.async_wait(boost::bind(&DeadlineTimer::runTimer, this));
        }
    public:
        DeadlineTimer() :t(io, boost::posix_time::seconds(2)){}
        void setFunction(std::function<void()> _f)
        {
            fun = _f;
        }
        void run()
        {
            io.run();
        }
    };

    void test()
    {
        DeadlineTimer timer1;
        auto f = []() {
            cout << "hello world\n";
        };
        timer1.setFunction(f);
        timer1.run();
    }
```

It allows user to pass a self-defined timer function via `timer1.setFunction(f);`. Then repeatedly run it (in every 2 second under current circumstance).

But it doesn't work, no output at all.

Comment: You are not calling `runTimer` anywhere in this code, so how do you want this timer to start?

Comment: Add `runTimer()` inside `setFunction` after `fun` was assigned.

Comment: @rafix07, Oh My, I just realize it. thank you.

Comment: @rafix07, yes, it works very well, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

After some trial-and-error, I’ve managed to update David Wyles’ boost::asio::repeating_timer class to work with Boost >= 1.66 - this neatly encapsulates  the functionality of a repeating timer.  Online at  https://github.com/mikehaben69/boost, including demo source and makefile.